# Unable to Connect to Cassandra Database from R using JDBC

Tags: r, cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

I am trying to connect R with Cassandra. Following is my code:

```
library(RJDBC)
#Load in the Cassandra-JDBC diver
cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
         list.files("D:/cassandra/lib",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))

#Connect to Cassandra node and Keyspace
casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.20:9042/demodb")
```

When I run above code in R, I get following error:

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1], :
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (--2080374784)!
```

Any ideas how to solve this error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BeyhanGül  No. I didn't find any Solution.

Comment: so, what did you do,alternatively

Comment: Now I'm not using R. so, I left it out.